# Error with apn_on_rails Multiple Apps

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, apple-push-notifications

I am using apn_on_rails with Multiple App support to send push notifications to my devices. The gem sends the notification but throws an error that says

> apn_on_rails-0.5.1/lib/apn_on_rails/app/models/apn/app.rb:35:in `read': No such file or directory - /config/apple_push_notification_production.pem

the certificate is being pulled from the database for the app but for some reason is still tries to use a default cert? How do I prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

Did you check their website?

> APN on Rails uses the Configatron gem,
>   http://github.com/markbates/configatron/tree/master,  to configure
>   itself. With the change to multi-app support, the certifications are
>   stored in the  database rather than in the config directory.
>
> However, it is still possible to use the default “app” and the
>   certificates stored in the config directory. For this setup, the
>   following configurations apply.) APN on Rails has the following
>   default configurations that you change for your setup.

Maybe you config still refers to it. Did you run the update?

> If you are upgrading to a new version of APN on Rails you should
>   always run:

```
ruby script/rails generate apn_on_rails:install
```